# Что такое «чибиряк»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

*Две гитары, зазвенев,

Жалобно заныли...

С детства памятный напев,

Старый друг мой — ты ли?

<...>

Перебор... и квинта вновь

Ноет-завывает;

Приливает к сердцу кровь,

Голова пылает.*

***Чибиряк, чибиряк, чибиряшечка,**

С голубыми ты глазами, моя душечка!*
[Аполлон Григорьев, Цыганская венгерка, 1857](http://www.moskvam.ru/publications/publication_1358.html)

Полюбопытствовала, поискала: нашла только *версии* возникновения *фамилии "Чибиряк"*, да и то — предположительные. Интересно, что же это такое — **чибиряк**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бесполезно искать смысл в этих словах, это заумь — такой литературный приём употребления не существующих в русском языке слов. Это — морфологическая заумь: существующие в языке морфемы (корни и аффиксы) сочетаются таким образом, что значение получающегося слова остается в значительной степени неопределенным. Возникновение зауми в качестве осознанного литературного приема относится к началу XX века, но ее предвестники существовали в культуре испокон веков. В целом ряде фольклорных жанров — особенно в заговорах — традиционно использовались необычные, не складывающиеся в слова сочетания звуков. Записи глоссолалии — бессвязной речи шаманов или фанатиков, впавших в религиозный экстаз.

Цыганская венгерка" — "тоскливый разгул погибшего счастья", по словам Фета, прощанье с невозвратимым прошлым, с любовью. Здесь — земная любовь, с неистовством, с пляской, чувственная любовь-тоска. А. Григорьев как раз переживал драму в любви, та, которую любил, вышла замуж (с голубыми ты глазами, моя душечка), вот он и выливает свою тоску в народной песне. К этому времени он увлекается цыганами, сам играет на гитаре, любит народные песни, хорошо знает всякие дворовые припевки — вот всё здесь и соединил. И что-то цыганское:

*Басан, басан, басана,

Басаната, басаната...*

Многие искали значение  этих слов, сами цыгане сказали, что в цыганском языке их нет, судя по корням, что-то вроде "пой, припевай". Вот и "Чибиряк, чибиряк, чибиряшечка..." — такая же заумь; здесь главное — ритмическое построение, подражание звучанию гитары, упоение звуком, который лишен смысла. А в говорах есть слово *чибер/чебер* — красавец, щеголь, франт, есть *чибать* — задирать. Кто его знает, что он имел в виду — может, "задира", может, красота, может, житель Чибира (реальная местность), а может, всё вместе — как поёт пьяная дворня (воспоминания детства). А дальше там:

*Что за горе? Плюнь да пей!

Ты завей его, завей

Веревочкой горе!

Топи тоску в море!*

И потом повторяется:

*Эх-ма, ты завей

Веревочкой горе...

Загуляй да запей,

Топи тоску в море!*

Народный говор, народные мотивы. В общем, это народный романтизм, страсть, данная без всяких рамок культурного сдержанного общества, где не всегда нужно искать смысл, главное — эмоции, а в песне — ритм, мелодия.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, рассуждение ходячее, но не абсолютно убедительное. Если заглянем в толковые словари старых русских слов, быстро обнаружим, что "басана" на многих говорах - это значит "красавица". Всего-то навсего. А согласно словарю Даля "чеберь" значит "франт", "щёголь", гуляка. Такой, как Аполлон Григорьев, например. Так что всё встаёт на места. Басана - красавица, чеберяк - её ухажёр.

Answer (score 0):

ЧЕБЕР
Мера для вина в Венгрии = ок. 7 русск. ведер.